Gap under the Bottom Navigation Bar
I have a pink gap between the bottom navigation bar and the action bar:

This is the bottom navigation bar xml:
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:backgroundTint="@drawable/nav_item_background_selector"
        app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@color/white"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_item_background_selector"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nev_item_select"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nev_item_select"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav" />

This is the themes xml:
<style name="Base.Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your light theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@drawable/card_gradients</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@drawable/card_gradients</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@drawable/card_gradients</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>

    </style>

nev_item_select
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/darkBlue"/>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@color/lightGray"/>
</selector>

nav_item_background_selector:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/white"/>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@color/white"/>
</selector>


can u share the code of the selecter too?

Check these possibilities... make sure there are no extra padding or margins specified in your XML layout or in styles applied to the view, consider to use ConstraintLayout for root layout, check parent layout constraints or attributes that might be affecting the positioning of the BottomNavigationView.

Updated the code

@DroidFlutter right

@DulithaBandaranayake in your themes file what is the card_gradients. can u please share it too?

This looks as if the window insets would be applied to both child and parent. Can you check that the parent consumes them properly?

issue was app:backgroundTint="@drawable/nav_item_background_selector" I change it to app:backgroundTint="@color/white" now its fixed. If you are using dark mode default this get system color.

So As DroidFlutter said do check the constraints and padding or margin properly in parent layout. If its fine I had faced a problem where there was unnecessary pink color in the selected icon and I fixed it this way.
So I changed the theme from themes.xml amd replaced it with
<resources>
    <!-- MyApplication is your application. you only need to change the parent theme -->
    <style name="Base.Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">


thanks for the answer. but issue was  app:backgroundTint in navigation bar. I set this color to white and now done!
